# Select List Based on Function Return Value

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a function which will return max value for me. In my view I have select list which i want  to show options from 1 - maxvalue . How can I implement this
thanks

```
function getmatch_value(){
 for (i=1;i<=7;i++){
  var left = $('#lc'+i).val(); 
  var right = $('#rc'+i).val(); 
   if(isblank(left) || isblank(right) ){
       var maxval = i-1;
       return maxval;
       break;
       }

 }
```

}

and i my view I have

```
<select id="match_ans2" name="mathRowAnswer[]" class="select" style="width: 150px;">
<option value='0'>Select Answer</option>
```

I want options based on my getmatch_value() so that if It will return 3 to me then the options list automatically have 1 2 and 3 options

Comment: I think it is not difficult to generate several `option` elements base on an array.

Comment: You've tagged this as `javascript` and `codeigniter`, and posted JS code. Can you clarify whether you're trying to generate the `option` elements in CI or JS?

Comment: Actually I have javascript function but I have to call this function on my view to generate options list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectList = document.getElementById('match_ans2');
for (var i = 1; i <= getmatch_value(); i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.toString()));
    selectList.appendChild(opt);
}
```